# How to stream live webcam video in AndEngine?

Tags: android, android-layout, video-streaming, webcam, andengine

Hi I'm using the game engine AndEngine, and I want to be able to stream live video from a webcam on a robot to my Android app. The reason I'm using AE is because I need game controls that control my robot. However, I have no idea how to stream video when using AndEngine (or even when not using it, for that matter). The controls and video feed need to be in the same screen (unless there's absolutely no other way). My question is how would one put a video stream over-top an AndEngine scene, and/or how would one format that feed so that it didn't obscure the controls? (they're oriented in the bottom left and top right of the screen, which is a pain I know, but I don't think I can change it due to some problems with multi-touch on my device). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Augumentged Reality example at GitHub. 
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples
It could be of use to you. However, I know that this example was problematic and didn't work when I tried it, but maybe you'll have more luck.

Comment: Thanks JohnEye. I took a look at it, and I couldn't get it to work either. I'm just going to use a webview and attach it to the scene, above the controls. In other words incorporating a webview into AndEngine. Could you possibly give me any advice on doing this? I've looked and found a few sources, but couldn't figure it out. App keeps force closing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't worked with webview yet so I can't advise you on that matter.